# Icinga - NagiosQL - NagVis - not writing services in Icinga databse

Tags: nagios

I've a fresh installation of NagiosQl 3.2.0 SP2, Icinga 1.8.4 and NAGVIS 1.7.9
 I had a running installation of NagiosQl, Icinga and NAGVIS (all older versions) before
 so i updated them all.
 So far, so good, all things are working, i see all OLD HOSTS and SERVICES in NagiosQL, Icinga and NAGVIS.

If I setup a new HOST or Service with NagiosQL, it will be shown in Icinga and NagiosQL but NOT in Nagvis if i try to ADD the new HOST or SERVICE to a map.

Ok, so far I checked it out, NAGVIS uses the Icinga DB to take a look what kind of HOSTs or SERVICEs are available. So it was in my old installation.

What happens?
 NagiosQL is not updating the Icinga DB (like it does in my old installation), instead the DB is simply empty. I've spend hours over hours to find out whats wrong so I have to ask here why NagiosQL updates his own DB but never the Icinga DB anymore.

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

NagiosQL is a configuration addon and does not update the Icinga IDOUtils DB (different applications, different databases!).

Likely your Icinga update went wrong. When you're saying that you've upgraded from an older version of Icinga you might have missed either some changes (e.g. 1.7 changing the idomod module name and location) or even forgotten to upgrade the db schema itsself.

either way, the upgrade documentation holds all valuable tips on that (next to the details on CHANGES in the Changelog): http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/upgrading_idoutils.html

Other than that, check your logs and make sure that Icinga and IDOUtils are operational. Details - https://wiki.icinga.org/display/testing/Icinga+Web+Testing#IcingaWebTesting-NoData

Comment: Well thank you for your suggestions. The update did indeed go wrong, so I did a whole new installation and finally it  does work, except some minor problems, but I think those are manageable.

Thank you so far for directing me into the right way and have a nice day (: